# sql server 2016 slower than 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

We recently moved from the following server: Windows Server 2008 R2 + MSSQL 2008 R2 STD to Windows Server 2012 R2 +MSSQL 2016 STD. In terms  of hardware, the old server was 1271v3 with 24 GB memory and the new server is 1271v6 with 32GB of memory. The rest of the hardware of the two servers is the same. The db was transferred using db backup and restore.

Although everything is working on the new server with no errors, it is significantly slower than the original server and we are even seeing some deadlocks.

If everything is the same or newer/better, how can this be?

Comment: there are several possibilities: update stats required, querystore turned for a large number of DBs (slowness not deadlocks), compatibility level ?

Comment: Allocation Unit Size can also be different and should be set to 64KB: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spucelik/2016/12/27/sql-server-disk-allocation-size/

Comment: Better to post to here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have updated stats and the compatibility level is set to the old db. Allocation is also the same.

Comment: Even if "everything" is slower, it helps to find some sample workloads and analyse them. Same query plans or not?

Comment: "The db was transferred using db backup and restore." - which suggests you might not have configured the new server correctly....

Comment: Compared the server settings several times - they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 4):

The problem was not SQL server at all. The new server was using the default Windows power plan which is "Balanced". Switching the plan to "High Performance" mode caused a performance increase of up to 300% on more complex and long running queries.